# Не закрывать окно на bootstrap-vue

Tags: bootstrap-vue

Подскажите как на bootstrap-vue реализовать чтоб при закрытии модального окна вывести сообщение, но чтоб окно не закрывалось ? В документации есть события hidden и hide, но они все равно закроют окно

Answer (score 1):

Нашел, может кому будет полезно bvModalEvt.preventDefault()

Comment: при помощи [Модификаторов событий](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9), в разметке это может выглядеть так `<b-modal @hide.prevent="hideHandler"></b-modal>`,